# Getting 'Invalid identity of application pool' error in Windows Server 2016 Docker container using aspnet image

Tags: asp.net, docker, iis, active-directory, windows-server

I am creating an image for Asp.net deployment.
I am using *mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet* docker image on Windows Server 2016 and after the first request to my site, App Pool is disabled.

Actually, I get this error:

*The identity of application pool PortalAppPool is invalid. The user name or password that is specified for the identity
may be incorrect, or the user may not have batch logon rights. If the identity is not corrected, the application pool
will be disabled when the application pool receives its first request.  If batch logon rights are causing the problem,
the identity in the IIS configuration store must be changed after rights have been granted before Windows Process
Activation Service (WAS) can retry the logon. If the identity remains invalid after the first request for the
application pool is processed, the application pool will be disabled. The data field contains the error number.*

I have the same error as this post:
[Getting 403: Forbidden Access Is Denied Error, trying to secure a site using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066735/getting-403-forbidden-access-is-denied-error-trying-to-secure-a-site-using-pow/7074863)

I checked my user with this command on the container:

```
runas /user:<username> cmd
```

And I get an identity error. But I am sure that the user identity information is correct.

And I used the same information for the App Pool identity information.
Can the problem be due to the lack of access to the container to the Active Directory?
If yes, considering that the host network type is not supported in windows containers, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you enabled "Log on as a service" for the account? Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a service. make sure your account is in this list directly or indirectly; it has also been suggested that you should set: Access this computer from the network; Deny logon locally; Log on as a batch job, also ensure that the account has "Read & Execute", "List Folder Contents" and "Read" access to the file system that underpins the web site/application.

Comment: @samwu, Thank you, but this suggestion did not work

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: @samwu - I will create a ticket from that way and I will inform the result here